# Getting a list of files in sass/compass

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm using sass and compass and I am trying to create css classes for images matching a given pattern.
The intended/resulting css mostly looks like this:

```
.class1 { background-image: url(class1.png); }
.class2 { background-image: url(class2.png); }
```

While it might be possible to use the compass sprite functionality ( http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/ ) it is inconvenient (as it will generate new files) in my case as the images are already spritesheets themselves.

So being able to do something like

```
@each $clazz in listFiles("images/*") {
  .#{$clazz} {
    background-image: url('#{$clazz}.png');
  }
}
```

would be great.
Is there a more or less easy way to do so?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can accomplish this by supplementing the builtin SASS/Compass functions with your own custom Ruby function. (See the section titled "Adding Custom Functions" in the SASS reference [here](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html).) Just define a Ruby file (say, "list-files.rb") with your custom code like so:

```rb
module Sass::Script::Functions
    def listFiles(path)
        return Sass::Script::List.new(
            Dir.glob(path.value).map! { |x| Sass::Script::String.new(x) },
            :comma
        )
    end
end
```

Then, you can include this file from your compass configuration file (say, "config.rb"):

```rb
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'list-files.rb')
```

And access it in your SASS stylesheet just like you want to:

```rb
@each $clazz in listFiles("images/*") {
  .#{$clazz} {
    background-image: url('#{$clazz}.png');
  }
}
```

You can then compile using `compass compile -c config.rb`, as normal.

Comment: That makes a list of the full file paths for me (ie images/filename1.png). Is there a simple way to get just the basename for ruby newbies?

Comment: @morewry Sure, just use Ruby's [File.basename](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-basename) method: `Sass::Script::String.new(File.basename(x))`.

Comment: Also you can use `Sass::Script::String.new(File.basename(x, ".*"))` to get just the filename without extension.

Comment: Is there a way to use regex to filter the returned list?